# For loop is not executed from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I tried to create a simple bat file to show part of file to another file, but it doesn't work. Just call it testing.bat

```
@echo off
echo result> output.dat
for /f "skip=1 delims=," %i in (input.txt) do echo %i>> output.dat
PAUSE
```

input file is simply comma-separated numbers, and I want to get every first numbers of each line (excluding the first line).
output file is empty.

But it stopped after printing "result" in output.dat

What I don't understand is, everything works perfectly if I just run the command from command line, but not from testing.bat

Any solution?
Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put another % before each % :)

So it should look like:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=," %%i in (input.txt) do echo %%i>> output.dat
```